# Problema de Schema Soap Laravel

Tags: laravel, soapclient

Olá, galera.
Estou tentando me conectar em um webservice soap usando o laravel.
Primeiro o webservice está em uma vpn, logo preciso fazer um proxy, porém estou tento dificuldades em consumir.
O meu erro é o seguinte.
SoapFault
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema. Namespace must not match the enclosing schema 'targetNamespace'

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://url/auth?wsdl');
    try {
        $client->validaUsuarioExterno(['login' => 'sandra.bondi.ws', 'senha' => 'xXdet8Yy']);
    } catch (SoapFault $excp) {
        die('Sem conexão '.$excp);
    }

    $passport = $client->validaUsuarioExterno(['login' => 'meu_login', 'senha' => 'minha_senha'])->passaporte;
    $function = 'obterDadosBoletoVeiculo';
    $arguments = array('obterDadosBoletoVeiculo' => array(
            'chaveConsulta' => '00011111100000',
            'tipoChave' => 1,
            'login' => 'meu_login',
            'passaporte' => $passport,
    ));
    // $options = array('location' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');        
    $clientConnect = new SoapClient('http://url/dados?wsdl');
    try {

        $result = $clientConnect->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

    } catch (SoapFault $excp) {
        die('Não foi possível retornar os dados, error: ' . $excp);
    }
```

Exatamente em: $clientConnect = new SoapClient('http://url/dados?wsdl');
ele me retorna o erro.

Comment: Você consegue abrir no navegar a URL: http://url/dados?wsdl ??

Comment: Sim, consigo.
Consigo acessar via SoapUi também